# Cannot add object with Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

With my Android project created with latest version of Eclipse+ADT I cannot access parse.com api. If I use the prepackaged project from parse.com I can access. But If I create a new Android project from scratch I cannot. I suspect the problem is because of parse initialization and fragments. As prepackaged project from parse.com doesn't use fragments. In this program first button should add an object to database but that doesnt work.. Can anyone know solution for this?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.deneme.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

**fragment_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.deneme.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="5.0dip" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCreate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Add Object"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnIncrement"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Increment votes"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.deneme"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name="denemeApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.deneme.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**denemeApp.java**

```
package com.example.deneme;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import android.app.Application;
public class denemeApp extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, "KEY1", "KEY2");
    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}
```

}

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.deneme;

import com.example.deneme.R;
import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        Button btnCreate = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("testobject");
            testObject.put("total_votes", 0);
            testObject.saveInBackground();
            }
        });

        Button btnIncrement = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnIncrement);
        btnIncrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //works with "testobject" and "7erUqKQn1P"
            //doesnt work "testobject2" and "1g68ZP1ikc"
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("testobject");

            query.getInBackground("7erUqKQn1P", new GetCallback<ParseObject>()
                {
                    public void done(ParseObject vote, ParseException e)
                    {
                        if(e == null)
                        {
                            vote.increment("total_votes");
                            vote.saveInBackground();
                        }
                    }//done
                }//new GetCallback
            );//query.getInBackground
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You need to declare the Internet Permission in you Manifest, did you already do that?

Comment: You just don't have initialised Parse in your MainActivity. I don't see any connection or inheritence between your mainactivity and the denemeApp class. Initialise Parse with your key in your MainActivity and check if that works.

Comment: @Ishan yes that was the problem thanks. But this time I faced another problem , if I try to increment another db object created by another project it fails. Do you have any ides?

Comment: @bilgehan I need to see your code for that.

Comment: @Ishan I updated code in btnIncrement.OnClick(). Basically I have 2 objects which are exactly same. They're named testobject and testobject2. testobject is created by the program I attached to this question and I can increment it . But If I change ParseQuery to fetch testobject2 I can't increment total_votes field in it. And testobject2 is created by another project..

Comment: @bilgehan are you calling update() method on the object after incrementing the values? You should open a new question for this problem with the code so that I can help. And should probably accept the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this permission to your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```